# Finding a Confidence Interval for a 2 player game

Tags: confidence-interval

It's been a while since I have done statistics so I am a bit rusty.  I'm playing a two person game which results in either a win or a loss.  I want to find a 95% confidence interval for a given players win rate over 50 games, 500 games, and 5000 games.

The player has won 40% of games at each testing point.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/confidence-interval-for-bernoulli-sampling
I assume "40% of games at each testing point" refers to the bernoulli parameter $p$. This provides a good overview of your problem.

Comment: thank you this helps a lot!

Comment: @shunjie Shouldn't the formula incorporate variance?

Comment: variance of $\text{Binomial}(n,p)$ is $np(1-p)$. The methods presented did made use of them.